# is it possible to get and create content organizer rules with csom?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

is it possible to get and create content organizer rules with csom

I am trying to migrate sites with csom, but I cannot find documentation on creating routing rules (CSOM), I appreciate if you leave me documentation or any guide

Comment: Check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150099/create-content-organizer-rule-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom-code